# Where abouts is the Broken Empire Trilogy set?

Tags: real-location, broken-empire

I am currently half way through the second book in the Broken Empire Trilogy by Mark Lawrence so if this gets answered in the books please mark answers with spoilers.

While reading these books it is apparent he has set them in this worlds future there are numerous references in the books. (Songs, structures etc).

Now and again locations will be mentioned but the names are not the original (due to mutation of language over a 1000's year I am assuming).   But since my geography is rather poor I am finding it hard to pinpoint where in the world he is basing this,  does any one know the location?

I understand the location is spread out a bit and might cross country boundaries.

Comment: It never gets "answered" specifically in the books, its always just left with the new names and lets you figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The trilogy is set in Western and Central Europe.

The map below (and this slightly larger one [here](http://www.marklawrence.buzz/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/map-king-of-thorns.jpg)) are directly linked from the author's [own website](http://www.marklawrence.buzz/book/) and show some of the corrupted names. Roma is central Italy, Normardy is Normandy, Andaluth is Andalucía, etc.

[image].

Comment: I have read his site and didn't find this. I never though to look for a map (face palm)

Comment: @Dreamwalker - On the author page listed, he's put a map under each book showing the main locations. As each book extends in scope, they seem to take in more territory.

Comment: doh yes spotted it was expecting the image ;)